# Order of a non-square rectangle with vertices and edges

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, symmetry

QUESTION:

> Suppose $B$ is a symmetry group of a non-square rectangle $R$ that has vertices $W, X, Y, Z$  as well as edges $h = WX, p = XY, k = YZ$ and $n = ZW$. And let $A$ be the set of all $2$-colorings of the set of edges $\{h, p, k, n\}$ of $R$ on which $B$ acts in the usual manner. Find $|B|$ and $|A|$ and then find the number of distinct $B$-orbits on $A$ with Burnside’s Counting Theorem.

I'm struggling with this question, but gave it a go anyways.

I noted that $|B|$ has order $4$ as it belongs to Dihedral Group $2$. Same with $|A|$. Would I also be right to assume the stabiliser for $W, X, Y$ and $Z$ is the identity?

Finally I put down the orbit of $W$ to be $(W,X,Y,Z).$

That's all I've done so far. However, something feels off. Could someone let me know if I'm on the right track so far (particularly with my order on $A$, as I've never come across the term $2$-colorings before)?

Thanks

Comment: Note: "symmetric group" means something in particular in group theory; you mean, "symmetry group".

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun I'll look into MathJax. And that's also correct, my mistake